# How to graph timeseries data with multiple groups

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I apologize if this is easier than it looks. I have pretty much zero experience making charts in Excel. However, I'm having a hard time finding information or knowing what to look for.

I have time series data showing the changes in file size over time. Here is a sample dataset:
[image]

I would like to graph the data grouped by file name. So, using the above data, I would want there to be 3 different colored trend lines (one for each file) showing "Length" on the Y axis and "LastWriteTime" on the X axis. I would want the flow of time to move evenly across the X-axis with the "LastWriteTime"/"Length" determining where each point on the graph goes. In other words, each increment on the X-Axis could be 1 day.

The layout / formatting of the graph is not important. Other methods are welcome as long as it can allow me to visualize the change in filesize over time for a specific file. The data layout can potentially change, but I would like to work with the format it is currently in.

Comment: Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj7yc.png ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a PivotChart:

[image]

You can Group the Date&Time in PivotTable and select the items you need:

[image]